# Unable replace \x.. sequence from a twitter feed in R

Tags: r, regex, twitter, str-replace, gsub

I've been grappling with regex in following string:

```
"Just beautiful, let’s see how the next few days go. \n\nLong term buying opportunities could be around the corner \xed\xa0\xbd\xed\xb2\xb0\xed\xa0\xbd\xed\xb3\x89\xed\xa0\xbd\xed\xb2\xb8... https://t dot co/hUradDaNVX"
```

1. I am unable to remove the entire `\x...\x` pattern from the above string.
2. I'm unable to remove `https` URL from above string.

My regex expression are:

```
gsub('http.* *', '', twts_array)
gsub("\\x.*\\x..","",twts_array)
```

My output is:

```
"Just beautiful let’s see how the next few days go \n\nLong term buying opportunities could be around the corner \xed\xa0\xbd\xed\xb2\xb0\xed\xa0\xbd\xed\xb3\x89\xed\xa0\xbd\xed\xb2\xb8... httpstcohUradDaNVX"
```

My expected output is:

```
Just beautiful, let’s see how the next few days go. Long term buying opportunities could be around the corner
```

P.S: As you can see neither of problems got solved. I also added dot for `.` in `https://t dot co/hUradDaNVX` as StackOverflow does not allow me to post shortened urls. Can some one help me in tackling this problem.

Comment: Try `iconv(x,"latin1","ASCII",sub="")` (this removes any non ASCII character).

Comment: Tried this solution, I'm still unable to get rid of those special characters. I get something like '������' on printing them

Comment: Please clarify: are you on Windows or Linux or Mac? On Windows, if I assign the string literal you provided at the beginning of the question to `x` and use `iconv(x,"latin1","ASCII",sub="")`, I get `"Just beautiful, lets see how the next few days go. \n\nLong term buying opportunities could be around the corner ... https://t dot co/hUradDaNVX"`, and [look, it works in Linux, too](https://ideone.com/eDelSR).

Comment: I'm on mac and i still get this output ""Just beautiful, let’s see how the next few days go. \n\nLong term buying opportunities could be around the corner \xed\xa0\xbd\xed\xb2\xb0\xed\xa0\xbd\xed\xb3\x89\xed\xa0\xbd\xed\xb2\xb8… https://t dot co/hUradDaNVX"./ I'll check on windows if that's the case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you can do the following:

```
twts_array <- "Just beautiful, let’s see how the next few days go. \n\nLong term buying opportunities could be around the corner \xed\xa0\xbd\xed\xb2\xb0\xed\xa0\xbd\xed\xb3\x89\xed\xa0\xbd\xed\xb2\xb8... https://t dot co/hUradDaNVX"

twts_array_str <- enc2utf8(twts_array)
twts_array_str <- gsub('<..>', '', twts_array_str)
twts_array_str <- gsub('http.*', '', twts_array_str)

twts_array_str
# "Just beautiful, let’s see how the next few days go. \n\nLong term buying opportunities could be around the corner ... "
```

`enc2utf8` will convert any unknown Unicode sequences to `<..>` format. Then it will be replaced by `gsub` with URL as well.